# How to parse YouTube video ID?

Tags: php, parsing, youtube

I need the ID of the YouTube video link. How to parse with PHP?

First link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**sEhy-RXkNo0**

Second link: https://youtu.be/**sEhy-RXkNo0**

Comment: please share the code of what you tried so far. you can try a regular expression (there are tools like <http://regexr.com/> to try them). if your stuck with your regex, share it and people will help you. Flagging your question as too broad...

Comment: The regex `/[\w\d-]+$/` works (see http://regexr.com/3e0vo), matching any char, digit and dash from the end of the string. But keep in mind that Youtube might change there ID format in the future (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/54448).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEhy-RXkNo0";    //youtube link

$data2 = "https://youtu.be/sEhy-RXkNo0"; 

$link= substr($data, strpos($data, "v=") + 2);  //for first link
$anotherLink = substr($data, strpos($data, "e/") + 2);   //for secondlink
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The second link doesn't work. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: for second link use $link= substr($data, strpos($data, ".be/") + 1);

Comment: $newlink= substr($link1, strpos($link1, "e/") + 2); //try this for second link it perfectly work in my php code

Comment: Thank you for the response. It was a misunderstanding. I want to get the ID of two different YouTube video link.

Answer (score 2):

Since the link won't always be in the nice format and may have another GET values it's better to use regex.

```
<?php
    $link1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEhy-RXkNo0";
    $link2 = "https://www.youtu.be/sEhy-RXkNo0";

    preg_match("/\?v=([^&]+)/", $link1, $id1);
    preg_match("/youtu.be\/([^&]+)/", $link2, $id2);

    $id1 = (isset($id1[1])) ? ($id1[1]) : (NULL);
    $id2 = (isset($id2[1])) ? ($id2[1]) : (NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It was a misunderstanding. I want to get the ID of two different YouTube video link.